# How to validate that job AWS Glue Python Shell, is actually running on a specific network (vpc)?

Tags: python, sql-server, amazon-web-services, aws-glue, pymssql

I currently have a job that has been executed several times within glue python, I have configured the usual parameters and I get a connection failed error on all executions. So when I debug my credentials with the source database (sql server managment) everything is fine, when I try to validate in the cloud (I only have the option to validate the glue connection connection and all is fine too) but it doesn't tell me if the correct network configuration is being used in the job.

Within of job i used AWS secrets_managers.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
        
CONNECTION = create_engine(
        f"mssql+pymssql://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{database_name}",
        pool_recycle=3600,
    ) # host is a IP
```

ERROR:

> "OperationalError: (pymssql._pymssql.OperationalError) (20002, b'DB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed (<HOSTNAME|IP>\nDB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed (<HOSTNAME|IP>)\n')"

I used external library of lib-in aws glue (version 3) libs:

> pymssql-2.2.10-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.whl

In job detailed already connection : (I took it out for safety reasons.):

[image]

**So, based on the previous information, I would like to know how to say "if I am 100% sure that my job is running on the VPC where it has a connection to my source database (because that configuration is fine, tested)."**

Comment: @AlwaysLearning and how do I install the driver of pyodbc if not use pymssql, within aws glue python shell ? : /